# How to configure wget to mass file download keeping the original filename

Tags: windows-7, download, wget

I have some problem configuring wget right for my needs,
i have a file, named images.txt, containing a list of urls to required images, 
the command for wget is simple: 
wget -i images.txt
however wget doesn't keep the original filenames, that are in the url, the filenames are very specific, for example all of the urls are look like this: http://somesite.com/someimage.jpg/123/456/789/, after downloading it converts a file to index.html, index2.html and so on. How do i configure it to save files as it is in the url: "someimage.jpg/123/456/789/" ?

Any help would be very helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the -x option, that'll create a directory structure, not sure if it'll save the filenames correctly but the doco suggests so.

http://linux.die.net/man/1/wget

Comment: Chris, thanks for an answer, but i can access these files only from the urls directly, the folder itself is not accessible.

Comment: Perhaps I should've clarified that it creates a matching local directory structure (those forward-slashes are treated by wget as directories). If you want a file literally called "someimage.jpg/123/456/789/", you won't be able to do that, because wget considers 123, 456 and 789 to be directory names.

Comment: OH, i see now, i think i have to to make some research on how to rename those output index1.html, index2.html, etc. files to what i have in the list, that would be the only decision in my case.